# CopyFile from current directory in c++ (windows API)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012

"myfile.doc" is in the same directory as the c++ executable.
But this gives me an error code 2!

```
CopyFile("myfile.doc","C:\\Destination\\myfile.doc",0);
```

Comment: @IInspectable sorry, my bad, I've deleted that comment.

Answer (score 1):

The current directory is not the same as the one with the executable.  You want to call [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) with a `NULL` `HMODULE` to get its path.

**Update:** Since you asked, here's a quick and dirty example with all error checks omitted (since your code example uses ANSI strings I will stick to `TCHAR`, as I say in comments in general I find it easier to just stay with `WCHAR` or `PWSTR` everywhere and compile for Unicode):

```
#ifndef ARRAY_SIZE
#define ARRAY_SIZE(X) (sizeof(X) / sizeof(*X))
#endif

// ISSUE - would be cleaner to do this on heap without artificial size limits
TCHAR Buffer[MAX_PATH];

PTSTR LastSlash;

if (!GetModuleFileName(NULL, Buffer, ARRAY_SIZE(Buffer)))
{
   // TODO - handle error
}

LastSlash = _tcsrchr(Buffer, _T('\\'));
if (!LastSlash)
{
   // TODO - this shouldn't happen.  treat it as an error.
}

LastSlash++;

TCHAR ToAppend[] = _T("myfile.doc");
if (ARRAY_SIZE(ToAppend) > ARRAY_SIZE(Buffer) - (LastSlash - Buffer))
{
   // TODO - you don't have enough space, this is an error
}

memcpy(LastSlash, ToAppend, sizeof(ToAppend));

if (!CopyFile(Buffer,_T("C:\\Destination\\myfile.doc"),0))
{
   // TODO - this is an error
}
```

Comment: And how would you pass that to "CopyFile" without type conversion errors. ' _Out_     LPTSTR lpFilename' and ' _In_  LPCTSTR lpExistingFileName,'

Comment: `GetModueFileName()` fills a `TCHAR[]` buffer that you provide. `CopyFile()` expects `LPTSTR` input values.  You can pass a `TCHAR[]` to a `LPTSTR`. So there is no mismatch.

Comment: @RemyLebeau TCHAR buffer[] 'unknown size'  and '+' : cannot add two pointers (buffer + "myfile.doc")

Comment: In addition to what @RemyLebeau says, you should ignore `TCHAR`, `PTSTR` etc., compile for Unicode, and use `WCHAR`, `PWSTR` everywhere when writing Windows specific code.  String literals should come prefaced with `L`, i.e. `L"Hello world"`.  If you need to work with a library that uses 8-bit strings (hopefully UTF-8) you should use `MultiByteToWideChar`, `WideCharToMultiByte`.

Comment: @asveikau Could you write that in a code snippet I can actually compile? I have the multibyte setting.

Comment: @sadmin - Done.  I haven't tested it but it should give you an idea.

Comment: @sadmin: obviously, you have to specify an actual size when declaring the `TCHAR[]` buffer, you can't declare it literally as `TCHAR[]`. As for appending values together, you can't use `+` with `TCHAR[]` and `LPTSTR`. You would need to allocate a new `TCHAR[]` that is large enough to hold the two values, and then copy them into it, such as with `lstrcpy()` and `lstrcat()`. This is where string classes come in handy, like `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`, which allows you to use `+` for concatenation, in addition to all the various string searching and manipulation methods it implements.

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on using a relative path. Instead construct a fully qualified pathname first. Start by retrieving the fully qualified path of the executable. [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) is the way to go:

```
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = {0};
GetModuleFileName(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);
```

To construct the fully qualified pathname of the file to copy you need to strip off the filename of the executable and append your filename. The Shell Lightweight Utility Library offers [`PathRemoveFileSpec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748.aspx) and [`PathAppend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773565.aspx):

```
PathRemoveFileSpec(path);
PathAppend(path, _T("myfile.doc"));
```

At this point, `path` holds the fully qualified pathname to your file `myfile.doc`, ready to be used in your call to `CopyFile`.

Note that this implementation is limited to pathnames of length `MAX_PATH` (260) characters. Also note that both SHLW calls have been deprecated in favor of safer alternatives [`PathCchRemoveFileSpec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707092.aspx) and [`PathCchApend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707081.aspx). The concepts remain the same; I went with the deprecated API calls for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running app from VS? IDE-s often change working directory of apps according to project properties. Try running app outside VS.